# Understanding Limits: $\infty - \infty = 0$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

$$(a).   \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} = +\infty$$

And

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{1}{x} = -\infty$$

But,

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{(-x)} = \lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{1}{x}$$

Hence,

$$(b).\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{(-x)} = -\infty$$

Adding equations $(a)$ and $(b)$, we have ;

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} + \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{(-x)} = \infty - \infty$$

Or

$$\lim_{x\to 0} 0 = \infty - \infty$$

But, we know that ;

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} 0 = 0$$

So, does $\infty - \infty = 0$ ?

Please explain what is happening above.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez   No. It don't

Comment: $\infty - \infty$ is indeterminate.

Comment: So how you explain $\lim {x\to 0^+} = \infty - \infty$ ?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ok. But,  the proof of what you stated above will be given to me in higher classes or is it simple? Please provide. Thanks !

Comment: @An_Elephant You just proved the statement in your post.

Comment: @Rodrigo I don't think it's a proof. Because it implies that we have believed it before proving.

Comment: @An_Elephant there are many ways to see why $\infty - \infty$ is indeterminate. A very easy one is: assume $\infty - \infty = 0$. Then, add, say, 2 both sides. Then we have $2 + \infty - \infty = 0 + 2$. But the left side of this equality remains $\infty - \infty$ since $2 + \infty = \infty.$ Therefore we also showed that $\infty - \infty = 2.$ This way we can basically "make" $\infty - \infty = $ "any number", and this is why it is indeterminate.

Comment: Let $c$ be an arbitary real number. Then $f(x)=x+c$ and $g(x)=x$ tend both to $\infty$ for $x\to \infty$. But $f(g)-g(x)$ trivially tends to $c$ , so you could argue $\infty-\infty=c$ for every real number $c$. The above comment shows that the difference can also tend to $\infty$ , hence we must consider this expression to be undefined.

Comment: You should go reread the definition of what the symbols "$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$" mean; there is no real number called "infinity", and the content of that limit is very different than if there were a real number $L$ on the right side.

Comment: Any calculus textbook had a discussion of "indeterminate forms".  Find one and read  that section.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes I have read. I think what I did wrong above was to add limits which were not finite and wanted more depth on it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The fundamental answer is that $\infty$ is not an actual number, but rather a class of numbers.  However, the real number system is not sufficiently complex to deal with infinite values in a meaningful way.

Imagine that, rather than asking if $\infty - \infty = 0$, you had instead asked if "an odd number minus an odd number is zero?"  Yes, there are odd numbers which, if added together, yield zero, but "odd number" by itself does not give you enough information to do that.

Likewise, you can't assume that two $\infty$s are actually equal to each other, so you can't use substitution and equality rules.  Just as I can't replace any given odd number with another odd number, I can't replace any given infinity with another infinity.

If you are interested in arithmetic with infinite values, you should check out the hyperreal number system.  However, I will warn you, a lot of things get weird with infinities, and there are currently more than one way to look at them.  This is certainly an area that needs more mathematical and philosophical work to get a system that totally encapsulates the ideas and nuances.

Comment: In the context of single variable calculus it is unambiguously false to say that infinity is a "class of numbers", in that context, there is no independent object called infinity, it is a notational device.  Understanding the hyperreal numbers is neither necessary nor sufficient to resolve the OP's confusion.

Comment: Ok I will look into hyperreal numbers sometimes later. Thanks